# Changing size of content in HorizontalScrollView when phone is rotated by overriding onConfigurationChanged

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, horizontalscrollview

Hello fellow Androiders...

I have a problem with resizing content in a HorizontalScrollView when the phone is rotated. I'm overriding onConfigurationChanged in my activity containing the HorizontalScrollView, since I want to handle the resizing myself. However, I'm having great problem finding where i should put the resizing of the content. The HorizontalScrollView it self has FILL_PARENT as width and a fixed height. The idea is that it should always fill the screen width-wise, while having several cells of content, each as wide as the HorizontalScrollView itself.

The content in my HorizontalScrollView consists of one LinearLayout (let's call it wrapperLayout) with several LinearLayouts inside it. When the phone rotates I simply want to change the width of all the LinearLayouts inside the wrapperLayout. This is easy to do and works great when I test the resizing code by putting it in onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev), that is the views are resized just as they are supposed to when I touch the HorizontalScrollView.

The difficulty appears when I try to find a good spot to execute resizing code, so that the resizing happens automatically when the phone is rotated. I have tried all possible combinations of requestLayout, onSizeChanged, onLayout, onConfigurationChanged and a few others and varying their calls to super (if any) before and after the resizing code. I can not make this work (the views are not resized even though the resize code is executed) and it is really frustrating. I've done a lot of logging to make sure the HorizonalScrollView really has changed width before calling my resize code but to no avail.

Does anyone have any clue as to what is going on? What methods are called and in what order when I handle the onConfigurationChanged by myself like this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

Is there a reason you are not using the viewcontroller's orientation calls. i.e.

```
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
```

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

I think it might be easier.

Comment: Sorry, should have clarified: this is using android :)